# How to list resources permitted to use other resource on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to list all resources which are permitted to write to s3 bucket.

Is there a way to list those resources?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The ability to write to an Amazon S3 bucket can be granted via:

- An IAM Policy attached to an IAM User, IAM Group or IAM Role
- A Bucket Policy attached to the S3 bucket

You won't actually know which 'resource' can use a particular IAM Role since the `AssumeRole` permission could again be granted to any IAM User, IAM Group or IAM Role.

Similarly, the Bucket Policy might grant access to a specific resource or might grant access to a range of resources.

**Bottom line:** You can review the policies and make educated guesses, but there is no ability to list exactly what resources can write to the bucket.